# Cannot call trigger on an empty DOMWrapper

Tags: vue-component, vue-test-utils, vue-jest

I am upgrading a Vue 2 component library to Vue 3. I have upgraded all the packages in the project, and made some necessary changes to get the code to compile. The components work as expected in a demo application.

Unfortunately, when I run the jest unit tests, I get a bunch of `Cannot call [something] on an empty DOMWrapper`. I found that jest does not seem to recognize the template definition in the `<template></template>` tag in the .vue file. However, if I define the template as a component property like:

```
export default {
  template: `<div class="component__wrapper">
              ...
            </div>`,
  name: 'Component',
  ...
```

the tests run fine and all pass.

Am I missing some crucial tidbit in the `jest.config.json`?

These are my relevant package versions:

```
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.3",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^29.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.9",
    "vue-loader": "^17.3.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
```

and my jest.config.json looks like:

```
{
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "testEnvironmentOptions": {
    "customExportConditions": ["node", "node-addons"]
  },
  "rootDir": "..",
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.*\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!(@storybook/.*\\.vue$))"
  ],
  "testRegex": "/__tests__/.*\\.spec\\.(ts|js)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "vue",
    "json"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$": "<rootDir>/jest/image-mocks.js"
  },
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "jest-serializer-vue"
  ],
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    ".d.ts$",
    ".stories.ts$",
    "index.ts$",
    "/__tests__/",
    "/stories/",
    "/types/"
  ],
  "coverageReporters": [
    "json",
    "lcov",
    "text",
    "html"
  ],
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 100,
      "functions": 100,
      "lines": 100,
      "statements": 100
    }
  },
  "clearMocks": true
}
```

Been pulling my hair out - if anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes to this question, the answer came from a coworker of mine. The solution was to change the script in the `.vue` file from:

```
<script>module.exports = require('./RadioButton.ts')</script>
```

to

```
<script lang="ts">
  import RadioButton from "./RadioButton";
  export default RadioButton;
</script>
```

Unfortunately, not really sure why that worked. If anyone has thoughts, feel free to comment.

Comment: Your project is a typescript project, not a JS project. Typescript uses the `import` esmodule syntax, where as you had used the CommonJS modules syntax: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/modules-in-javascript